# How to run sqlcmd with parameters from batch and assign return value to a variable?

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an MS SQL script that takes two variables and does what its supposed to do, return a single value.

In my batch file, I call this script as follows and I get the output I expect.

```
sqlcmd -v ALM_Domain=%dom% ProjectName=%proj% /h-1 -S %DB% -E -C -i GetDBNameForDomainProject.sql
```

However, I need to use the value returned by the query in my subsequent processing, and decided I'd like to assign the return value into a variable. To do so, I used the following construct

```
for /F usebackq %%a IN (`sqlcmd -v ALM_Domain=%dom% ProjectName=%proj% /h-1 -S %DB% -E -C -i GetDBNameForDomainProject.sql`) do (
    set DBNAME=%%a
)
```

for which I get the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: 'NCA ProjectName SIM': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

**Notice the '=' sign seems to have disappeared**. Help for the for command states:

Finally, you can use the FOR /F command to parse the output of a
command.  You do this by making the file-set between the
parenthesis a back quoted string.  It will be treated as a command
line, which is passed to a child CMD.EXE and the output is captured
into memory and parsed as if it was a file.

If I attempt to use:

```
for /F %%a IN ('sqlcmd -v "ALM_Domain=%dom% ProjectName=%proj%" /h-1 -S %DB% -E -C -i GetDBNameForDomainProject.sql') do (
    set DBNAME=%%a
)
```

I get:

```
Sqlcmd: 'ALM_DOMAIN=NCA ProjectName=SIM': Invalid argument.
```

Answer (score 3):

Having nothing to do with your problem - USEBACKQ is rarely needed when executing a command with FOR /F. Its primary use is to enable reading from a file that contains spaces or poison characters in the name, which require quotes to preserve. But double quotes normally indicate a string value, hence the need for USEBACKQ

```
for /f "usebackq" %%A in ("file name with spaces.txt") do ...
```

If you are executing a command, then all you need are normal single quotes, *without the USEBACKQ option*.

```
for /f %%A in ('someCommand.exe') do ...
```

You certainly can use USEBACKQ with the backtick, but I see no benefit.

Now for your actual problem - you have noticed that the parser has converted your `=` into a `<space>`. This is a "feature" of the batch parser which must parse the command into a string that gets executed by `CMD /C`. The parser treats `=`, `,`, `;`, `<tab>`, `<space>`, and `<0xFF>` as token delimiters, and any contiguous string of token delimiters is transformed into a single `<space>`.

The solution is to either enclose the entire command within double quotes (inside the outer single quotes that signify a command), or escape the problem characters. In your case, I believe you can use the double quotes.

```
for /F %%a IN ('"sqlcmd -v ALM_Domain=%dom% ProjectName=%proj% /h-1 -S %DB% -E -C -i GetDBNameForDomainProject.sql"') do (
  set "DBNAME=%%a"
)
```

Not an issue with your case, but if your command already uses double quotes, then the alternative is to escape the `=`.

```
for /F %%a IN ('sqlcmd -v ALM_Domain^=%dom% ProjectName^=%proj% /h-1 -S %DB% -E -C -i GetDBNameForDomainProject.sql') do (
  set "DBNAME=%%a"
)
```

Comment: Thanks dbenham. You answered my question very clearly, and I tried it both ways with the double quotes inside the singles, and escaping the equals sign.